# Detecting material separation in images

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I have an image set of material flowing through a spiral witch separates two types of mass based on their weight. I need to be able to detect where the mass separates vertically in the image.  When observed with the naked eye it's clearly shown as there is a gap between and a slight color variation (brown/gray).
In this example image it's separated approximately in the middle.
[image: Example image]
What is the best way to start exploring this case?